# How to install private key and root certificate on Linux server

Tags: linux, apache, ssl, certificate

I have a linux server with apache tomacat running on that . In my application I am using a two way SSL authentication and the server is generating a certificate for each and every client for mutual authentication using a root certificate and signing it with a private key.

But I am not aware how to install the private key and root certificate on my server. Is it possible using putty as there is no user interface enabled on server.

Comment: Either use scp / WinSCP or copy & paste the contents of the private key and certificate files. They should both contain printable characters only.

Comment: Can you please tell where I need to copy the certificate and private key file (Directory path)?

Comment: Copy it to any directory you want, but it must be accessible by the tomcat user. Then configure the tomcat to [serve SSL requests](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html).